# Cannot login if requiressl is set to true

Tags: ssl, requiressl

I have a live web site in IIS 7.5. I can login to my site correctly with http protocol till I add this line in Web.config:

> httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"

All configuration for SSL is done but I cannot login anymore with both http and https although the cookie **.ASPXAUTH** is created.

If I set **requireSSL="false"**, I can login normally.

Please help!

Comment: What error do you get from IIS?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and as I came across this post searching for a solution I can explain what happened: your application was configure to use secure cookies and this requires the browser to issue the request over SSL. Therefore, if requireSSL attribute is set to true, you can't log in to your website with Http